# PDF Password not working properly in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfrenderer

I am creating a PDF using  `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData( pdfData, self.rect, dictionary);`

I set `dictionary=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:masterPassword,kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword,password, kCGPDFContextUserPassword, kCFBooleanFalse, kCGPDFContextAllowsCopying, kCFBooleanTrue, kCGPDFContextAllowsPrinting,  nil];`

When i give kCGPDFContextUserPassword with more than five characters, the kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword is not working. Please someone help me with this issue.

You can find a pdf example [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4dVHHQcNQ01bVdrbXJqS3RrWG8/view?usp=sharing.).

This pdf contains: kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword as "admin", kCGPDFContextUserPassword as "qwerty".

Comment: In which scenarios does it work correctly? In which scenarios does it not work correctly? Does it sometimes work and not work for the exact same password, or is it possible you're using characters not allowed by PDF passwords? What have you tried?

Comment: Assume I give the kCGPDFContextUserPassword as "12345" and kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword as "admin". It works perfect in this scenario. When I change kCGPDFContextUserPassword as "qwerty" the "admin" password is not working. I couldn't figure out a test case.

Comment: Can you post a non-working PDF file? Also specify the passwords used with the file.

Comment: @iPDFdev I upload a pdf and edited my question as a found a scenario.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I found a scenario and modified the question that explains it.

Comment: Are your variables 'masterPassword' and 'password' setup correctly? This 5 characters limit looks like a buffer overflow, the 'password' damages the 'masterPassword'.

Comment: @iPDFdev I tried with hard coded values. Doesn't work.